# Getting ng-show value as reference

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I have the following html:

```
<div ng-show=showMarketingNav>
    ...
</div>

<div ng-show=showProductsNav>
    ...
</div>

<div ng-show=showSettingsNav>
    ...
</div>
```

What I want to do is to easily be able to hide all but one of the divs from another controller. I thought I could be clever and do the following:

```
var subNavMenuDisplays = {
    Marketing: $scope.showMarketingNav,
    Products: $scope.showProductsNav,
    Settings: $scope.showSettingsNav
}

$rootScope.hideContextMenu = function () {
    for (var category in subNavMenuDisplays) {
        subNavMenuDisplays[category] = false;
    }
}

$rootScope.setContextMenu = function (name) {
    $rootScope.hideContextMenu();
    subNavMenuDisplays[name] = true;
}
```

but this obviously does not work as $scope.showMarketingNav etc. will be passed as value, not reference.

The following works, but is not exactly nice to work with:

```
$rootScope.hideContextMenu = function () {
    $scope.showMarketingNav = false;
    $scope.showProductsNav = false;
    $scope.showSettingsNav = false;
}

$rootScope.setContextMenu = function (name) {
    $rootScope.hideContextMenu();
    if (name == "Marketing") {
        $scope.showMarketingNav = true;
    }
    if (name == "Products") {
        $scope.showProductsNav = true;
    }
    if (name == "Settings") {
        $scope.showSettingsNav = true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to grab $scope.showMarketingNav by reference, or another clever way around this?

I'd prefer not using eval to concatenate variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place an object on the $scope and then toggle it dynamically:

```
$scope.show = {};

$rootScope.setContextMenu = function (name) {
    $scope.show = {};
    $scope.show[name] = true;
}
```

And the Html:

```
<div ng-show="show.Marketing">
    ...
</div>

<div ng-show="show.Products">
    ...
</div>

<div ng-show="show.Settings">
    ...
</div>
```

Here's a [plunker demonstrating](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMSvNy?p=preview) the change.

Comment: Very clever. In hind sight, it's pretty obvious that if I want the flag to be referable I should just stuff it inside an object. Bonus point for making it even easier to work with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign simple updater functions in that object:

```
Marketing: function(val) { $scope.showMarketingNav = val },
Products: function(val) { $scope.showProductsNav = val}, 
Settings: function(val) { $scope.showSettingsNav = val}
```

Then call it:

```
subNavMenuDisplays[name](true);
```